# I want to login everytime with new user but Cy.session recreate session with same user again

Tags: cypress, cypress-session

I Have pageObject Login File in which I am creating a session while login

```js
login(username,password){
        cy.session('sessionId', () => {
            cy.visit('/');
            this.getUsername().type(username);
            this.getPassword().type(password);
            this.getLoginButton().click();
            cy.url().should('contain', '/inventory.html');    
        },
        {
            validate: () => {
              cy.url().should('contain', '/inventory.html');
            }
        }
     )
}
```

I have stored username and passwords in cypress.config file in form of objects

```js
env : {
      users : {
        standard : {

          username : "standard_user",
          password : "secret_sauce"

        },
        lockedout : {

          username : "locked_out_user",
          password : "secret_sauce"

        },
        problem : {

          username : "problem_user",
          password : "secret_sauce"

        },
        glitch : {

          username : "performance_glitch_user",
          password : "secret_sauce"

        }
      
 }
```

I am calling this page object login function for different username but Cy.session recreates session with same username for evry test

```
describe('All users', () => {

    const login_page = new LoginPage();

    const users = Cypress.env("users");

    Cypress._.each(users,(user) =>{

        it('work for the user ', () => {

            cy.log(user.username);

            login_page.login(user.username,user.password);
        
        });


    }) 
    
});
```

Please guide me how can i login everytime with a new user.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [examples](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Updating-an-existing-login-custom-command) there's an option to base the session id on the incoming parameters.

So instead of

```js
cy.session('sessionId', () => {
```

using

```js
cy.session([username, password], () => {
```

will provide a unique session id for each combination of `username` and `password`.

You could also use `cy.session(username, () => {` but including the password allows you to run tests for same user but with both valid and invalid passwords.

Each session data is stored separately for each login.